# How to check whether a List<String> contains a specific string?

Tags: java, list, loops

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have some `List<String>`, I want to print a statement if the List contains a particular string, else throw an Exception but when I try the following code

```java
List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
fruit.add("apple");
fruit.add("orange");
fruit.add("banana");

for(int i = 0; i < fruit.size(); i++){
   if(fruit.get(i).contains("banana"){
     System.out.println("Found");
   } else {
     throw new SkipException("could not be found");
   }
}
```

it iterates through the List and at `i = 0` it obviously finds "apple" and immediately goes to the `else` block and throws exception. I also tried the following, but this didn't work either.

```java
for(int i = 0; i < fruit.size(); i++){
   if(Arrays.asList(fruit).contains("banana"){
      System.out.println("found");
   }else{
      throw new SkipException("not found");
   }
}
```

Is there an easy way to do what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: please refer to following link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Are you trying to find whether the list contains the string 'banana' or if any of the strings in the list contain the substring 'banana'?

Comment: @JimmyJames, i'm trying to find if the list contains "banana" not substring... If that makes sense

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**There are a few ways.**

Which one you choose is up to you, there's a tradeoff between verbosity, being constrained to a simple equals check (if you want to do more complicated matching, you can't easily do Option 1), and using newer APIs that you might not yet support or be familiar with.

**Option 1**: *The [Collection.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#contains-java.lang.Object-) method:*

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("orange");
fruits.add("banana");

if (fruits.contains("banana") {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    throw new SkipException("could not be found");
}
```

**Option 2**: *Using a `for` loop with external state:*

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("orange");
fruits.add("banana");

boolean found = false;
for (String s : fruits) {
    if (s.equals("banana")) {
        found = true;
        break; // Break out of the loop to skip the remaining items
    }
}
if (found) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    throw new SkipException("could not be found");
}
```

**Option 3**: *If you're using Java 8, the neat [Stream.anyMatch()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch-java.util.function.Predicate-) method:*

```
List<String> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add("apple");
fruits.add("orange");
fruits.add("banana");

if (fruits.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.equals("banana"))) {
    System.out.println("Found");
} else {
    throw new SkipException("could not be found");
}
```

Option 3 is my personal favorite, as it's nearly as compact as Option 1, but allows to to provide a more complex [Predicate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Predicate.html) if you want a comparison based on something other than the `equals()` method.

Comment: can you explain option 3 how it translates with for loop? what does .anyMatch (what is s)?
does it mean it is going to check "apple"=="banana" and so forth?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to iterate through the array list. Once you call `list.contains("someString")`, it will check for that string in that entire array list. Therefore, the following is enough.

```
if(fruit.contains("banana"){
     System.out.println("Found");
} else {
     throw new SkipException("could not be found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this
if at any index the value is equal to "banana" and it will print found else it will throw exception

```
   List<String> fruit = new ArrayList<>();
   fruit.add("apple");
   fruit.add("orange");
   fruit.add("banana");

   boolean result;
   for(int i = 0; i < fruit.size(); i++){
      result = fruit.get(i).equals("banana");
      if(result){
        break; // Early exit if found
      }
   }

   if(result){
      System.out.println("Found");
   } else {
      throw new SkipException("could not be found");
   }
```

Solution 2:
when working with arraylists you dont need to iterate through every index manually rather arraylist gives you a function "contains()" that will automatically check if the desired value is present at any index or not so simply you can do this:

```
    if(fruit.contains("banana"){
         System.out.println("Found");
    } else {
         throw new SkipException("could not be found");
     }
```

Comment: Downvoted because this will behave (with the given input) identically to OP's solution. Your code will never print `"Found"`, as the first element encountered will be `"apple"`, and the exception will be thrown erroneously.

Comment: thanks for pointing that out I hope the second solution is fine

Answer (score -1):

Try using a boolean to detect whether you have found the fruit in your list of fruits. Something like this:

```
boolean inlist = false;

for(int i = 0; i < fruit.size(); i++){
   if(fruit.get(i).equals("banana"){
        inlist = true
        break;
   }
}

if (inlist) {
    System.out.println("found");
} else {
    throw new SkipException("not found");
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing 1: using booleans like this is bad style 2: you can just call the List contains method 3: even if you did want to loop, you should use foreach ':' instead of a loop on the index.

Comment: @JimmyJames do you have a reference as to why using booleans like this is considered "bad style"? I realize there are specific methods/utilities to handle this use-case, I'm only interested your #1 comment.

Comment: @RayfenWindspear It's a bit subjective and the explanation is too long for a comment but my opinion (and one that seems to be popular on SO) is that you should put your logic in the if in the loop and return from there.  The style you are using is often taught in school but is long out of favor in the industry based on what I see.

Comment: So your saying that the downvoter didn't like the style? The content and correctness wasn't in question? If that's the case then I say Mr(s) downvoter you are a jerk!