# Is there a reason this won't work? I have the || operators right, can you compare user inputted strings using the ||?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

It says "error: bad operand types for binary operator '||'"

```
if(a.equals("skels" || "iceS" || "fireS" || "elecS" || "healS")) {
    card1 = 1;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of a?

Comment: `a.equals("skels") || a.equals("iceS") || ....` - You need to use the `||` operator on the booleans that the equals method returns, not on the Strings that you pass into the method

Comment: Strings aren't boolean values, so you cannot compare them with `||`.

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37330551/how-to-check-whether-a-liststring-contains-a-specific-string) for a few ideas on how to do it properly.

Answer (score 2):

A value cannot be two values, if that makes sense.

equals takes one value, and the operator `||` is a logical or that takes two booleans.

You are using it in a wrong context.

**Elaboration**

```
String a = "Hello"; //does mean, that a has now the value "Hello"
```

It can be used as a parameter, for example in the equals-Method:

```
boolean result1 = a.equals("Hello"); //or
boolean result2 = "Hello".equals(a);
```

Both of these uses of equals take one String and return one boolean.

You can also write something like

```
boolean b = "Hello".equals("World") || "Hello".equals(a);
```

Which would set the value of `b` to `true`, and not `false or true`.

Why?

- `"Hello".equals("World")` is false
- `"Hello".equals(a)` is true
- `false || true` is true

The `||` operator (just as `&&` and `^`) works in a boolean context, where only booleans can be compared.

Writing smth like:
`String a = "Hello" || "World";` makes no sense, cause neither are "Hello" or "World" true or false. They are Strings.

With that in mind, you can compare and use multiple equals statements in a boolean expression; Because they return booleans, which these operators can work with.

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the `equals` methode multiple times and move the `||` out of the `equals` call, like this:

```
if(a.equals("skels") || a.equals("iceS") || a.equals("fireS") || a.equals("elecS") || a.equals("healS")) {
    card1 = 1;
}
```

Comment: Just a comment: for `null` safety it's better to compare a literal string to a variable.